# Flink CEP greedy matching

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm having a bit of a battle with the Flink CEP greedy operator.

Given the below java code:

```
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1,3,5,5,5,5,6,".split(","));

    DataStream<String> input = env.fromCollection(strings);

    Pattern<String, ?> pattern = Pattern.<String>
    begin("start").where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
            return value.equals("5");
        }
    }).oneOrMore().greedy()
    .followedBy("end").where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {

        @Override
        public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
            return value.equals("6");
        }
    });

    PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(input, pattern);

    DataStream<String> result = patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String select(Map<String, List<String>> pattern) throws Exception {
            System.err.println("=======");
            pattern.values().forEach(match -> match.forEach(event -> System.err.println(event)));
            System.err.println("=======");
            return "-";
        }
    });

    result.print();
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
```

I would like to see: only "5 5 5 5 6" emitted

However, it matches "5 5 5 5 6", "5 5 5 6", "5 5 6", "5 6"

If I do:

```
    begin("start").where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
            return value.equals("3");
        }
    }).followedBy("middle").where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
            return value.equals("5");
        }
    }).oneOrMore().greedy()
    .followedBy("end").where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {

        @Override
        public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
            return value.equals("6");
        }
    });
```

However, (thus providing a different starting match) the Greedy operator works as expected by emitting "3 5 5 5 5 6".

Is it possible to have a greedy matcher grab all matches without having a different starting pattern?

Or am I missing something?

Stephan

Comment: I've been playing with the 
org.apache.flink.cep.nfa.NFA class and its process(....) method.

Looking at:   discardComputationStatesAccordingToStrategy(computationStates, result, afterMatchSkipStrategy);

The only result I'm interested in is result[0].

Playing with the code, it doesn't look like "afterMatchSkipStrategy" will allow me to get only the largest match.

Comment: have you been try use `.until` to replace `.followedBy` after `.oneOrMore().greedy()` ?

Comment: Thanks Leyla.

I've given that a go and tried a few more ways of using until as well, but I'm still getting the non greedy matches published.

I feel I'm missing something in my understanding of the CEP engine implementation here, as this would appear to be a rather common use case, no?

Stephan

Comment: Did you find a solution/understand how it works? I am facing a similar issue. If you use for example a GlobalWindow and a custom Trigger you could probably evict messages 5,5,5,6 Does this notion not apply in Flink-CEP

Comment: There's a know bug about greedy matching that may explain the behavior: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8914

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the update! Glad to know I'm not fishing in the wrong pond :P

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chesnay Schepler's for his comment above:

> There's a know bug about greedy matching that may explain the behavior: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8914

I'll note this as the answer for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

To control to how many matches an event will be assigned, you need to specify the skip strategy called AfterMatchSkipStrategy.

use Pattern.begin("start", AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipPastLastEvent())

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1,3,5,5,5,5,6,".split(","));

DataStream<String> input = env.fromCollection(strings);

Pattern<String, ?> pattern = Pattern.<String>
        begin("start", AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipPastLastEvent()).where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
  @Override
  public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
    return value.equals("5");
  }
}).oneOrMore().greedy()
        .followedBy("end").where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
          @Override
          public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
            return value.equals("6");
          }
        });

PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(input, pattern);

DataStream<String> result = patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public String select(Map<String, List<String>> pattern) throws Exception {
    System.err.println("=======");
    pattern.values().forEach(match -> match.forEach(event -> System.err.println(event)));
    System.err.println("=======");
    return "-";
  }
});

result.print();
env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
```